custom defconst
I'm trying to build a function that is a wrapper around defconst so that creation of a constant automatically gets logged in my log file. However, I can't figure out how to pass a string in a variable in a way that can be read by the defconst function as a comment. Could you advise what trick I am missing? Is this a macros use case or am I over complicating things?
I have consulted the elisp manual and had a google but I've failed to find or recognize the relevant information.
My code so far is below.
(defun myTools/defconst(const-name val comment)
  "Automatically log the creation of a constant.
CONST-NAME:  the name of the constant (symbol).
VAL:         the value the constant takes (any).
COMMENT:     documentation of the comment (string)."
  (setq debug-on-error t)
  (debug)
  (let ((comment-string  (format "%s" comment)))
    (progn
      (my/log-to-file
       (format
        "[%s ; INFO; init.el] Created constant %s. s%; s%;"
        (myTools/current-time-with-milliseconds)
        (symbol-name const-name)
        comment-string
        (format "%s" val))
       init-log)
      (defconst const-name val comment-string))))


https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

defconst is a "special form" which means there's no guarantee of arguments being evaluated.  The first argument especially you know cannot be evaluated, because the normal usage:
(defconst foo 42 "doc")

Creates a variable named foo, not a variable named from the evaluated value of foo (which would in any case make little sense when you're in the process of defining foo as a variable).
Hence your (defconst const-name val comment-string) defines a variable named const-name.

Is this a macros use case

Yes; you can use a macro to generate a defconst form containing the evaluated value of const-name.

Thanks for this! I'll have a read up on macros, write & test the code then post it and accept your answer. Should be in the next day or so.

Following up on this, my solution was to use the below macro:
    (defmacro my-utils/defconst (const-name value description)
      "Automatically log the definition of a constant."
      `(progn
         (defconst ,const-name ,value ,description)
         (log/info :fn 'init
                   :msg (concat "defined constant: " (symbol-name ',const-name))
                   :obj (list :value ,value :description ,description))))


In order to use it though, you would also have to deploy my admittedly over-elaborate logging function setup which I include (with apologies) for completeness.
;;;; custom-logging-config.el --- Emacs logging configuration  -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-

;; Copyright (C) 2023
;; SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

;;; Commentary:
;; Set up logging in Emacs.


;;; Code:


;; Avoid issues from large objects being converted to strings.
(customize-set-variable
 'print-length 500
 "Set the maximum length of list to print before abbreviating.")


;; Implement basic logging in Emacs.
;; set up logging
;; --------------

;; set up log path.
(defconst log/init-log "~/.emacs.d/init.log"
  "The path to the log file used when loading Emacs.")

;; define log levels.
(defconst lvl/FATAL (list :idx 0 :lvl "FATAL") "The FATAL log level.")
(defconst lvl/ERR   (list :idx 1 :lvl "ERR")   "The ERR log level.")
(defconst lvl/WARN  (list :idx 2 :lvl "WARN")  "The WARN log level.")
(defconst lvl/DEBUG (list :idx 3 :lvl "DEBUG") "The DEBUG log level.")
(defconst lvl/INFO  (list :idx 4 :lvl "INFO")  "The INFO log level.")

(defun log/current-time ()
  "Return the current time as a string with microsecond precision."
  (let*
      (
       (now (current-time))
       (seconds (float-time now))                       ; Get time in seconds (float).
       (microseconds
        (truncate (* (mod seconds 1) 1000000)))         ; get microseconds
       (time-in-seconds
        (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" now)))  ; Get the standard time
    (format "%s.%06d"  time-in-seconds microseconds)))  ; Add microseconds


(defun log/write-to-file (message log-file)
  "Write a log to file, creating or appending as necessary.
This function mirrors \"my/append-to-file\" and is defined so
logging can be set up without loading dependencies.
MESSAGE:    A string to be appended to the file (string).
LOG-FILE:  A path to a file (string)"
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert message "\n")
    (append-to-file (point-min) (point-max) log-file)))

(defun log/logger (&rest args)
  "Base logger function for the session.
Note that any object passed will be converted to a string and truncated at no
more than the number of characters in \"print-length\".
If the object is a string, it will not be truncated and any formatting symbols
contained (\\n for example) will be respected in the print to file.

ARGS:
    LOGFILE:  The filepath for the log (symbol).
    LVL:      The logging level (symbol).
    FN:       The function being logged (symbol).
    MSG:      The log message (string).
    OBJ:      An object to be recorded.

RETURNS:
    nil"
  (let ((logFile (plist-get args :logFile))
        (lvl (plist-get args :lvl))
        (fn (plist-get args :fn))
        (msg (plist-get args :msg))
        (obj (plist-get args :obj)))

    (log/write-to-file
     (format
      "[%s; %s; %s] %s; %s;"
      (log/current-time)
      (plist-get lvl :lvl)
      (symbol-name fn)
      msg
      (prin1-to-string obj))
     logFile)))

;; Define the log levels used in the system.
(defun log/fatal (&rest args)
  "Function to log a message at log-level `FATAL.
ARGS:
   FN:       The function being logged (symbol).
   MSG:      The log message (string).
   OBJ:      An object to be recorded."
  (let ((fn (plist-get args :fn))
        (msg (plist-get args :msg))
        (obj (plist-get args :obj)))
    (log/logger
     :logFile log/init-log :fn fn :msg msg :obj obj
     :lvl lvl/FATAL)))

(defun log/error (&rest args)
  "Function to log a message at log-level `ERROR.
ARGS:
   FN:       The function being logged (symbol).
   MSG:      The log message (string).
   OBJ:      An object to be recorded."
  (let ((fn (plist-get args :fn))
        (msg (plist-get args :msg))
        (obj (plist-get args :obj)))
    (log/logger
     :logFile log/init-log :fn fn :msg msg :obj obj
     :lvl lvl/ERR)))

(defun log/warn (&rest args)
    "Function to log a message at log-level `WARN.
ARGS:
   FN:       The function being logged (symbol).
   MSG:      The log message (string).
   OBJ:      An object to be recorded."
  (let ((fn (plist-get args :fn))
        (msg (plist-get args :msg))
        (obj (plist-get args :obj)))
    (log/logger
     :logFile log/init-log :fn fn :msg msg :obj obj
     :lvl lvl/WARN)))

(defun log/debug (&rest args)
    "Function to log a message at log-level `DEBUG.
ARGS:
   FN:       The function being logged (symbol).
   MSG:      The log message (string).
   OBJ:      An object to be recorded."
  (let ((fn (plist-get args :fn))
        (msg (plist-get args :msg))
        (obj (plist-get args :obj)))
    (log/logger
     :logFile log/init-log :fn fn :msg msg :obj obj
     :lvl lvl/DEBUG)))

(defun log/info (&rest args)
  "Function to log a message at log-level `INFO.
ARGS:
   FN:       The function being logged (symbol).
   MSG:      The log message (string).
   OBJ:      An object to be recorded."
  (let ((fn (plist-get args :fn))
        (msg (plist-get args :msg))
        (obj (plist-get args :obj)))
    (log/logger
     :logFile log/init-log :fn fn :msg msg :obj obj
     :lvl lvl/INFO)))

(log/debug :fn 'custom-logging-config
           :msg "Providing custom-logging-config."
           :obj t)

(provide 'custom-logging-config)
;;; custom-logging-config.el ends here

